# Differentiate.$ y = \frac{7x}{ 6 − \cot x}$

Tags: calculus

I have no idea what I have done wrong. Please criticise. [image]

Comment: let the critizing begin then...

Answer (score 3):

You are just off by a negative sign. You say that you say $\frac{d}{dx} [6-\cot(x)]= -\csc^2(x)$, but it should be  $\frac{d}{dx} [6-\cot(x)] = \csc^2(x)$. This means you should get $$y' = \frac{42-7\cot(x)-7x\csc^2(x)}{(6-\cot(x))^2}$$ Does this match what you would expect?

Comment: I shouldn't distribute the negative sign?

Comment: Well, there isn't really one to distribute since you have $(-7x) \cdot (\csc^2(x))$

Comment: Okay, the second line of my work, after I calculated the derivative of 6-cot x; which is 0 - (-csc^2x), is there no need to distribute the negative sign? May be this is a basic math problem; however, I would like some to explain to me if I am doing "illegal math".

Comment: Nothing illegal going on, $-(-\csc^2(x)) = \csc^2(x)$. Then you still have to multiply that quantity by $-7x$, so the negative sign appears again. $$-7x(0-(-\csc^2(x))) = -7x\cdot 0 -7x \cdot -(-\csc^2(x)) = 0-7x(\csc^2(x)) = -7x\csc^2(x)$$

Comment: So -(a)(b) not -[(a)(b)]

Comment: There is no difference between those two